# Python list out of bounds

Tags: python, list, parsing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following function in python that takes input and parses it into a dictionary.  I am trying to pass it the following input and for some reason on the lines `artist=block[0]` causes it to break because the list index is out of range and I am really confused why. It breaks after reading in the second `Led Zeppelin`. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Input

```
Led Zeppelin
1969 II
-Whole Lotta Love
-What Is and What Should Never Be
-The Lemon Song
-Thank You
-Heartbreaker
-Living Loving Maid (She's Just a Woman)
-Ramble On
-Moby Dick
-Bring It on Home

Led Zeppelin
1979 In Through the Outdoor
-In the Evening
-South Bound Saurez
-Fool in the Rain
-Hot Dog
-Carouselambra
-All My Love
-I'm Gonna Crawl

Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

Bob Dylan
1966 Blonde on Blonde
-Rainy Day Women #12 & 35
-Pledging My Time
-Visions of Johanna
-One of Us Must Know (Sooner or Later)
-I Want You
-Stuck Inside of Mobile with the Memphis Blues Again
-Leopard-Skin Pill-Box Hat
-Just Like a Woman
-Most Likely You Go Your Way (And I'll Go Mine)
-Temporary Like Achilles
-Absolutely Sweet Marie
-4th Time Around
-Obviously 5 Believers
-Sad Eyed Lady of the Lowlands
```

Function

```
def add(data, block):
    artist = block[0]
    album = block[1]
    songs = block[2:]
    if artist in data:
        data[artist][album] = songs
    else:
        data[artist] = {album: songs}
    return data

def parseData():

    global data,file
    file=os.getenv('CDDB')
    data = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        block = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                data = add(data, block)
                block = []
            else:
                block.append(line)
        data = add(data, block)
        f.close()


    return data
```

Comment: You don't need `f.close()`. The context manager does the job for you.

Comment: `block = []` is an empty array. Therefore `block[0]` is out of range. Debug your code to find out under what circumstances `block` is equal to `[]` when you try to access `block[0]`.

Comment: Whenever the parser tries to parse in the block starting with `Hello` is when block is equal to []. What would cause this?

Comment: I tried you code with your data.It works fine. Looks like you have tow empty lines in a row in your real data.

Comment: I found the problem. It was an empty at the end of the file.  Is there anyway to ignore that line?

Comment: Just check `if not block: return`

Answer (score 2):

Just add a sanity check to your `add()` function:

```
def add(data, block):
    if not block:
        return
```

Also, there is no good reason to use global variables. Here's an illustration:

```
def parseData(path):

    data = {}
    block = []

    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                add(data, block)
                block = []
            else:
                block.append(line)
        add(data, block)

    return data
```